# Is there a way to apply a filter to a treestore that includes a property that does not exist on one of the models specified?

Tags: rally

I am trying to populate a treegrid with user stories and defects, but one of the parameters that I would like to use in the filter is a property that does not exist on the defect model.

If the filter includes that property, no results are returned.  Is there a workaround or special filter definition?

Answer (score 0):

The treegrid/treestore request data from the artifact wsapi endpoint.  There is a hidden queryable field called TypeDefOid that you can use to limit a filter to a specific type, like so:

```
((TypeDefOid != <defectTypeDefOid>) OR ((TypeDefOid = <defectTypeDefOid>) AND (DefectField = "value")))
```

You can obtain the defectTypeDefOid from the model once the treestore is built:

```
var defectTypeDefOid = treeStoreModel.getArtifactComponentModel('Defect').typeDefOid;
```

You can see a good example of this in action in the IterationTrackingBoardApp here:

https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/blob/master/src/apps/iterationtrackingboard/IterationTrackingBoardApp.js#L227

That example is for story, but very similar.  Just below that in the code is also a more complicated defect specific filter as another example.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer!  This provides exactly the query help I needed, and the example was on point.

Comment: Follow up: There must be some differences in the implementation of the gridstore component of the treegrid (as opposed to the "standalone" treestore), because the compound selections as used in the example don't work.  What I get is essentially an unfiltered list of all of the user stories and defects (named in the models definition for the treegrid).